# Flot, jsrender & phantom: Bar label axis

Tags: flot, jsrender, jsreport

I set up a jsrender based flot chart with jsreport.net and currently fail with the y axis of the charts on multi-pages. As you can see on the second image, the y axis doesn't match the bars correctly.

**Update: Here's the playground link:**: https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/WJmSGjkB5/2

**First page:**
[image: First page]

**Second page:**

[image: Second page]

**Here's the current source code snippet**

```
        var seriesCount = 1; // current data series identifier

        // drawing series hook
        dsHook = function(plot, canvascontext, series){
            for (var i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++){

                // get relative position of plot
                var offset = plot.offset();

                // get data point
                var dP = series.data[i];

               var pos = plot.p2c({x: dP[0], y: dP[1]});

               var barWidth = plot.p2c({x: dP[0] + series.bars.barWidth, y: dP[1]}).left - pos.left;

               var posCorr; 
               // set horizontal position correction

               switch(seriesCount) {
                   case 1: posCorr = -72; break;
                   case 2: posCorr = -23; break;
                   case 3: posCorr = 24; break;
                   case 4: posCorr = -50; break;
                   case 5: posCorr = 2; break;
                } 

                pos.left += offset.left + posCorr; 
                pos.top += offset.top - 30;

                numFormatted = number_format(dP[1], 0, '', '\'');

                var aDiv = $('<div></div>').css({'width':barWidth, 'background-color':'white','color':'black','font-size':'12px','text-align':'center','position':'absolute','left': pos.left,'top':pos.top}).text(numFormatted).appendTo("body");

            }
            seriesCount++;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure its not a css issue? your container may not be the right size for any flot generated elements.

Comment: The css div has following attributes:
width: 700px;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 50px auto;

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a JSFiddle to see whats going on there? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: jsfiddle didn't work out, but I created a playground directly with jsreport.net: https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/WJmSGjkB5/2

Comment: The y axis matches the bars, only the labels above the bars are at a wrong position. If you change the renderer to html the labels are at the correct position, so the problem seems to be with phantom-pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `plot.offset().top` gets wrongly calculated in `dsHook` because of a space for header/margin added for every another page.

The first "solution" is to modify your calculation to reflect this:

```
pos.top += offset.top - 30 + ({{:ID}}-1)*20;
```

https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/WJmSGjkB5/5

The Second "solution" is to add fixed sized empty header to the phantom configuration, don't have an explanation for it yet

https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/WJmSGjkB5/4

I hope I'll update this with better explanation/solution

Comment: Indeed very strange, thanks a lot for your two solutions, which both work (perfectly). Would be very interesting to getting to know why it's the way it is.